# Capturing a thread_local variable by reference in lambda does not work as expected

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda, capture, thread-local

I'm currently building a system where I have multiple threads running, and one thread can queue work to another thread and wait for completion. I'm using mutexes and condition_variables for synchronization. In order to avoid creating a new mutex and cv for each operation I wanted to optimize it and tried to use a thread_local mutex/cv pair for each thread that is waiting. However this was unexpectedly not working, and I would be interesting why.

Basically my code which queues work into the other thread and waits for it looks like:

```
/* thread_local */ std::mutex mtx;
/* thread_local */ std::condition_variable cv;
bool done = false;  

io_service.post([&]() {
    // Execute the handler in context of the io thread
    functionWhichNeedsToBeCalledInOtherThread();

    // Signal completion to unblock the waiter
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        done = true;
    }
    cv.notify_one();
});

// Wait until queued work has been executed in io thread
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
    while (!done) cv.wait(lk);
}
```

This works fine if the synchronization objects are not `thread_local`. When I add `thread_local` the waiting thread waits forever, which indicates that the condition variable is never signaled. I now have the feeling that despite capturing the objects by reference the thread_local objects of the other thread are used inside the lambda. I can even confirm that the capture is not doing the correct thing by checking the address of `mtx` inside and outside of the lambda -> They don't match.

The question is:

- Is this a bug in the compiler or by design? I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and haven't checked with other compilers yet.
- Is capturing `thread_local` variables by reference even permitted?

I can work around the error by creating an explicit reference to the `thread_local` variables outside of the lambda and using those references inside it. However I think the behavior is unexpected and would love to hear an explanation whether this is correct behavior or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you observe is the correct behavior, as you are not actually capturing anything. Static and thread storage duration objects are accessible directly, so in the interest of efficiency `[&]`-capture has no effect on those. You can however capture appropriate thread local instances explicitly:

```
io_service.post([&mtx = mtx, &cv = cv]() {
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. Actually if I don't specify `[&]` at all, I can still refer to `mtx` and `cv`. They seem to be implicitly in scope for a lambda without requiring the capture. Without `[&]` the behavior makes sense, it was just unexpected that trying to capture everything by reference actually does not capture the thread_local variables. Btw: A reference to a specification or documentation for this behavior would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For a *mutex* to work every thread needing synchronization must lock the **same** mutex. What `thread_local` does is create a different *mutex* for each thread. If your threads each have their own, independent *mutex* they can't possibly communicate through them. You need **one** *mutex* for all your threads to share.

The same is true of *condition variables*. All threads need to be 'talking' to the same *condition variable*. That means it does not makes sense to have a separate *condition variable* for each thread.

Regarding your lambda, each thread that *instantiates* the lambda will capture it's own copy of the `thread_local` variables. Given that the *mutex* and *condition variable* you access from the lambda are otherwise accessed from a different thread there is no synchronization as your lambda is working with a completely different set of variables.

Comment: I totally understand that both threads need to work on the same mutex and cv - that was not the question but just the description where the behavior was observed. What I do not understand is the capturing behavior, which is neither "capture by-reference" nor "capture by-value". It seems to be some kind of "capture by-label". The question is where this behavior is described and if it's really standardized.